# libc malloc vs linux kernel buddy allocator

Tags: linux-kernel, malloc, memory-fragmentation

Does malloc wory about internal fragmentation in linux kernel?
For example when I want to allocate 5 pages, will malloc round up size to make it power of 2: 5->8 to avoid internal fragmentation in kernel, because linux kernel uses buddy system as page allocator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least for glibc, it doesn't really care about fragmentation in the kernel. It is mostly a "best-fit" allocator except for very small or very large allocations. Here is an extract from the comments near the top of glibc's "[malloc.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=malloc/malloc.c;hb=HEAD)":

> - Why use this malloc?
>
>   This is not the fastest, most space-conserving, most portable, or
>     most tunable malloc ever written. However it is among the fastest
>     while also being among the most space-conserving, portable and tunable.
>     Consistent balance across these factors results in a good general-purpose
>     allocator for malloc-intensive programs.
>     The main properties of the algorithms are:
>
>   - For large (>= 512 bytes) requests, it is a pure best-fit allocator,
>       with ties normally decided via FIFO (i.e. least recently used).
>   - For small (<= 64 bytes by default) requests, it is a caching
>       allocator, that maintains pools of quickly recycled chunks.
>   - In between, and for combinations of large and small requests, it does
>       the best it can trying to meet both goals at once.
>   - For very large requests (>= 128KB by default), it relies on system
>       memory mapping facilities, if supported.
>
>   For a longer but slightly out of date high-level description, see
>     http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html

The glibc `malloc` implementation is fairly tuneable using the `mallopt` function or various environment variables to set various parameters, as described in the man page [mallopt(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallopt.3.html).