# memory allocation in the power of two vs multiple of eight

Tags: c, unix, memory-management, operating-system, malloc

Is it better to implement a memory allocator which always allocates memory in power of (2)? Are there any alternate efficient ways say multiple of (8) allocation? Will there be fragmentation issues for allocation logics like multiple of (8) allocation?

Comment: What is allocating in powers of two? Do you mean the allocator only allocates blocks of sizes (in bytes) 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, and so on, and never blocks of sizes such as 768? Because your alternative is multiples of eight, which would allow 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, and so on, including 768. I would not expect allocating only power-of-two sizes to be good overall.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I think that OP means 2,4,6,8,10 ... or 8,16,24,32 ....

Comment: IMO it will not make any difference. Remember that you need to mind the alignment too

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, the comparison between allocating blocks of sizes 2,4,8,16,32,64,128 vs 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48. I already coded power of 2, evaluating if I replace it with multiple of 8 will there be fragmentation issues.

Comment: @Ram: There can be fragmentation issues either way, depending on the design of your allocation code and the behaviors of its clients. Some programs will allocate and release memory in ways that cause more fragmentation, and some will allocate and release memory in ways that cause less fragmentation.

Comment: Assuming you are asking for an allocation scheme of your own array ADT or similar, then this has been asked before, I can't be bothered to find the duplicate. Essentially: it makes sense to allocate n * word size. Where word size is 4 on 32 bitters, 8 on 64 bitters and so on. And for such an ADT, whenever you run out of memory, you generally realloc twice the previous amount, to reduce the number of realloc calls.

Comment: If you use powers of 2, your user who wants 17 GB is going to be mad about wasting a further 15 GB...

Answer (score 1):

There is this thing called [buddy memory allocator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_memory_allocation) and it is a thing in Linux kernel, but it is used for allocating *physical page frames*, not virtual memory.

[Jemalloc](http://jemalloc.net/) seems to implement a buddy memory allocator for virtual memory.

---

There is no benefit when using *operating system `malloc`*  to allocate memory in powers of 2 - in fact it will **waste** memory when using Glibc malloc - this is because an allocation of 128 KiB would actually allocate *one page more* using `mmap` and use the extra page of memory just to store a couple pointers. If you need a block of memory and are concerned about wasted space, you wouldn't use `malloc` but the operating system `mmap` directly.

Comment: I think Glibc malloc uses a buddy system with fixed-size bins for small allocations, but uses mixed-size bins for larger allocations, and `mmap` for even larger allocations. For the fixed-size bins, the usable block size would be a power of two minus the per-block overhead.

Comment: @IanAbbott not really: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57996975/libc-malloc-vs-linux-kernel-buddy-allocator

Comment: Yeah, your right. Successive small fixed-size chunk sizes go up by 8 or 16 bytes.